# Adding html page into a variable for an email body Yii

Tags: php, html, email, yii

I have a function inside my controller that whenever actionCreate happens, it calls my emailAll() function. Within my emailAll(), there's a line of code that allows me to input the body of the message:

```
 $message->setBody('To view announcement, click here:  '.$url);
```

But as you can see, this is a boring body for an email. I'll create an html page that has all the information but I don't know how to add the entire HTML page inside the setBody().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code.

```
$message->setBody(
    $this->renderPartial("email_content_view_file",
             array("url"=>$url),true,false), 'text/html'
 );
```

Comment: Hmm, it took the page but it wasn't in html. It even showed the html tags.